# Dynamic Header works just on index.html

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm building a website that's having a header with a function(if I scroll down it makes the header smaller). Problem is that on index.html it works properly but on my second-page in,t working. And to create the second page I just copied the first page and added some extra content.
Does anyone know what can be the issue?

```js
// SCROLLING EFFECT 
const mainNav = document.querySelector('.header');
const img = document.querySelector('.logo');


// Change size of logo↓↓↓
if (getComputedStyle(mainNav).height == '70px') {
  img.style.height = '70px';
} else {
  img.style.height = '100px';
}
// when scrolling down, make it smaller↓↓↓
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
    mainNav.className += ' small';
    img.style.height = '70px';
  } else {
    mainNav.classList = 'header';
    img.style.height = '100px';
  }

})
```

```css
.header {
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<!-- !Header -->
<header class="header  ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-content">
      <img src="/Core/img/logo1.jpg" class="logo" alt="logo">
      <div class="menu-links">
        <ul class="links-list">
          <li><a href="/Core/index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Core/biography.html">Bio</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Core/training.html">Training</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Academy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**First Page**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Lazar Angelov</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- !Header -->
  <header class="header ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header-content">
        <img src="/Core/img/logo1.jpg" class="logo" alt="logo">
        <div class="menu-links">
          <ul class="links-list">
            <li><a href="/Core/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Core/biography.html">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Core/training.html">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Academy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="social-links">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


  <!-- !FOOTER -->
  <footer id="main-footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="footer-content">
        <ul class="policy">
          <li>
            <small><a href="#">Copyright &copy; 2017 L.A. Fitness Group LTD</a></small>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><small>Privacy Policy</small></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><small>Terms and Conditions</small></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><small>Cookie Policy</small></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="social-links">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Second Page**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Lazar Angelov</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- !Header -->
    <header class="header  ">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header-content">
                <img src="/Core/img/logo1.jpg" class="logo" alt="logo">
                <div class="menu-links">
                    <ul class="links-list">
                        <li><a href="/Core/index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Core/biography.html">Bio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Core/training.html">Training</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Academy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="social-links">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- !FOOTER -->
    <footer id="main-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer-content">
                <ul class="policy">
                    <li><small><a href="#">Copyright &copy; 2017 L.A. Fitness Group LTD</a></small></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><small>Privacy Policy</small></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><small>Terms and Conditions</small></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><small>Cookie Policy</small></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="social-links">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how do you include your header code in second page? Post your second page code  to get clear idea of what you're doing. Also are you using php in your code or just pure html and javascript?

Comment: your js code probably isn't used in second page.

Comment: I added index.html and second page

Comment: But how can be used just on one page because i have linked the js file on both html pages

Comment: Did you see any error in console...? Because the second page is too working with your js...

Comment: It was an error in my console,Thank you!

Comment: Either post an answer and accept it or delete your question, please. Abandoned posts are ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the error in the console in every page not just on index.html maybe is an error on a specific page.